# Any way to simulate Process.fork() on Windows?

Tags: windows, forking

I need to use a library that seems to be making the assumption that Process.fork() is available.

On Windows it is not.

I tried installing Cygwin with the idea that it might simulate this.

Didn't work.

Any other ideas to get this working on Windows (Vista-32)?

Comment: What library do you need to use ?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985281/what-is-the-closest-thing-windows-has-to-fork

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the link given by caliban, but if it's too technical then the simple answer is : Not easily possible, as the Unix and Windows models for process operations differ by too much. The link suggests that Cygwin can, with a truly heroic effort, make Windows work as Unix (I would like to see it working before I believe in it). I would suggest that you replace your forks by spawns for improved compatibility.